# The completion block doesn't execute for twilio get media url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

The question is why the completion block not executed at the line
`imgURL = url ?? ""`.

When I am debugging, it stops at the line `msg.getMediaContentTemporaryUrl` and then all the block are skipped executing the return.

```swift
func getImageURL(_ msg:TCHMessage)->String {
        var imgURL : String = ""
        msg.getMediaContentTemporaryUrl { (result, url) in
            imgURL = url ?? ""
            print("getImage Function: ",imgURL)
        }
        return imgURL
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what msg.getMediaContentTemporaryUrl does?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples of the rest of the languages in the official documentation:

[Twilio docs for getMediaContentTemporaryUrl](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/media-support?code-sample=code-creating-a-media-message&code-language=Android%20-%20Java&code-sdk-version=default)

What you are defining inside the curly brackets is a callback executed asynchronously, so you will get there once the request is done.
If you want to stop when you reach that point, you will need to add a breakpoint to the line
`imgURL = url ?? ""`
, for example